# Should I remember the payment before getting it authorized?

Tags: paypal

I get it that Paypal SDK (backed by REST API) has three steps:

1. Create a payment

   ```
   payment = Payment({...})
   payment.create()
   return redirect( redirect_url( payment))
   ```
2. The customer pays and authorizes payment from within Paypal
3. Redirect to our site where we execute payment, thus transferring money

Should I **store the created payments at step 1**? I would thus capture all payment attempts, whether successful or not. Or can I create a payment, and not remember it until step 3? That is, record only the successful payments (within their respective Invoices). Is there any reliability or security issue or other **harm** if I do not store it at step 1?

I suspect not being able to roll back failures.

---

In Paypal terms, they are of `sale` intent and are meant for payment of invoices for services rendered. Card data do not touch our servers, I am deferring to Paypal on handling it.

I use paypalrestsdk, Paypal's Python SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, it was tricky to get the PaymentId back when PayPal redirects the page back to your server to authorize you, as there was no way to get PaymentId on 3rd step

However, now, the PaymentId is returned back as a part of the URL as shown here in 3rd step :

```
http://localhost/Server-SDK/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/payments/ExecutePayment.php?success=true&paymentId=PAY-62998961VU1587338KR3AXWQ&token=EC-4YC2489096181311L&PayerID=REABK2UGK7PLW
```

As you can see it has paymentId which is the Id that you need to store. 
So, to answer you dont need to store anything till 3rd step.

Additional Note:

However, if you have some complicated logic/service you want to provide. E.g. send them an email reminder(if you have their emailId), to remind them if they abandoned your card, etc. However, there are many ways to do that besides using these steps.