# How to get the Transaction ID using PayPal Express Checkout Integration (Client-side REST)

Tags: javascript, php, rest, paypal, client-side

I would like to get the transaction ID once the Paypal payment is succesfull.

I am using [Paypal Express Checkout (Client-side REST)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/).

Please find below my code for the payment button.

My objective is to be able to update the MySQL database to (1) confirm the order and (2) include the Paypal transaction ID next to it. This is what the orderconfirmed.php file will aim to do once it is called. For that I need to be able to get the TransactionID variable when the payment is succesfull

```
<script>
          paypal.Button.render({

              env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'

              client: {
                  sandbox:    'ABCD',
                  production: 'ABCD'
              },

              commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

              payment: function(data, actions) {
                  return actions.payment.create({
                      payment: {
transactions: [
    {
        amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' },
            item_list: {
            items: [
                {
                name: 'hat',
                description: 'Brown hat',
                quantity: '1',
                price: '0.01',
                currency: 'USD'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
                      },    
                  });
              },

              onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                  return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {

                        document.querySelector('#confirmmessage').innerText = 'Thank you - Your payment has been processed';
                        document.querySelector('#paypal-button').style.display = 'none';
                        document.querySelector('#confirmdiv').style.display 

= 'block';
window.location.href = 'orderconfirmed.php?transactionID=HOW_TO_GET_THIS_FIELD';
                      });
                  }

              }, '#paypal-button');
          </script>
```

Comment: did you read https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create_request ?

Comment: Yes I did but I dont understand how this is relevant for me. I am using the client side integration. If my understanding is correct the codes you refer to are curl commands on the server to create a payment object. I cannot do that as i am using a shared hosting service. Am i missing something?

Comment: you should be able to do the same via JS. but shared hosting does not mean you can't use curl.

Comment: what does data contain, does it have the sale id?

Comment: Just use the data returned onAuthorize, paypal returns the paymentID and orderID window.location.href = "https://yourwebsite.com/orderconfirmed.php?payment=" + data.paymentID + "&order=" + data.orderID;

Answer (score 5):

So here is the solution I found to my issues

1- to get the PaymentID you can simply do (as inarilo rightly so suggested - thanks!)

```
data.paymentID
```

Note: the PaymentID is different from the TransactionID: see [Difference between paymentId and TRANSACTIONID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445740/difference-between-paymentid-and-transactionid)

To get the Transaction ID, I use:

```
payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id
```

2- then to use this information and update the MySQL Database through PHP, I use AJAX.

so put together the code looks like that:

```
                        document.querySelector('#confirmmessage').innerText = payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id;


       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","testajax.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();


                        document.querySelector('#confirmdiv').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: What it the object payment? Could you add so context to this line of code? Thanks **payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id**

Comment: UPDATE: the above is valid for checkout.js.For the new integration with SDK (from Feb 2019), the transaction ID can be found at **...purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id**